# Replace application specific urls which aren't already link objects

Tags: javascript, replace, jira

A web application (JIRA) doesn't support application specific urls but integration of JavaScript. I want to replace all application specific `app://*` link strings on the html page.

```
<div class="action-body flooded">
    <p>app://foo.bar?var1=param1</p>
</div>
```

Currently I easily do it with the following:

```
function rewriteLinks() {
    var expression = /(app:\/\/[\w.,@?^=%&;:\/~+#-]+)/g;
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(expression, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
};

window.onload = function() {
    rewriteLinks();
}
```

Example html string: `app://foo.bar?var1=param1`

Expected output: `<a href="app://foo.bar?var1=param1">app://foo.bar?var1=param1</a>` and don't replace existing a tags

The problem is that in some cases app:// links will be already real html links. The attributes `href` and `innerHTML` of links will be replaced by the code. So existing links will be broken.

Is there any more robust way to replace just non app:// link (not surrounded by `a`) objects?

Comment: what are you replacing there? are these urls just plain text? In general I'd say, don't play around with `innerHTML`, but at the moment I don't get what's actually in your markup and how you want that to be replaced.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your comment. I added an expected output. Becomes more clear? I know that I shouldn't manipulate (all) page content. As far as I can see there is no other option to realize this feature for non-http links. Implementation was already requested https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-26419...

Comment: OK, read the ticket. So the point is that some links get converted properly, other don't? Because You mention problems with Nodes that are already parsed and built/rendered in HTML. And can you add the actual HTML markup your're dealing with, because, well, context matters.

Comment: @Thomas Added a fragment. Sure, context matters.The code should replace all specific urls (`app://`) but real html anchors.